# Flutter - How to close OS related permission dialog without user interaction?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to close OS related permission dialog without user interaction ?

USE CASE Example -  if camera permission dialog is prompted in Android / IOS while requesting camera permission and user did not allowed permission in specific time then it should close the dialog.

I'm expecting to close the dialog after specific time if user did not allow / deny the permission. but don't want dialog to be visible unless user closes manually.